# Typing a pipe function in js with flow type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

So I have the following pipe function in js that I have typed with flow:

```
const pipe = (...fns: $ReadOnlyArray<any>): any => (param: any) => fns.reduce((result, fn) => fn(result), param)
```

and I was hoping to maybe allow *some* typing and use the `mixed` type like so:

```
const pipe = (...fns: $ReadOnlyArray<mixed>): mixed => (param: mixed) => fns.reduce((result, fn) => fn(result), param)
```

But flow gives an error message of:

> flow: error
>   infer - fn (Cannot call 'fn' because mixed [1] is not a function.)

See online here: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1ABwJa4CmoAvKABQB0NkmAXKACQBKRAhgCYDya0AngEEATsPb8APOzT8AfAEpG0-mVmVc7MQFslM+atB0MVYUU4BXZEQoVTGc9CwAaQ2n2k1dW0XuP5LjW15RBR0bDxCIgAmMkoaKiNGVg4ePiFRcQktfAAPMwVGbLzOAwpA9h1QIrN3T0wTM0trb19nV1rXFocsfzxNCvkgA

Its not the end of the world if i have to use the `any` type, but I was wondering why I cant use the `mixed` type? I mean it's allowed to take a function according to the docs: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/mixed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined, that function takes any number of arguments which can be anything. Yes, that includes functions, but it also includes, for example, numbers. What would happen if you called `pipe(5)`?

Instead, it seems like you want to restrict it to functions only. This is simple to do -- just replace `$ReadOnlyArray<mixed>` with `ReadOnlyArray<mixed => mixed>`. With that change, the function typechecks.

However, that's still not a very useful type. It will be frustrating to use the result, since it's `mixed`. That means that Flow doesn't know anything about its type, so you will be forced to refine it before using it. And, runtime refinements can only go so far.

This function would be much more useful if it were polymorphic:

```
const pipe = <T>(...fns: $ReadOnlyArray<T => T>): (T => T) => {
  return (param) => {
    return fns.reduce((result, fn) => fn(result), param);
  };
}

function plus5(x) { return x + 5; }
function times3(x) { return x * 3; }
const plus5times3 = pipe(plus5, times3);

(plus5times3(6): number);
// expected error
(plus5times3(6): string);
```

([playground](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBADgSzgUxgXhgHgCoD4AUAdMQGaQBcMAJAErICGAJgPJgA2AngIIBOP9HHOlww8ASkr5sw0WJkBvAFAwYPZFACuPMDHxx6-ALZy0IpSoCQazdphkIhNYw3Bk+fGoga2UADR2wExEyD2QvHzF-fSMxAG5lGABfeMTFRRINMGAoBHB4Ng0IAFZ8AA85eVV1LR1SmABqGCLYpPTM7NydHMMwgGYyiqqbWpgAKhheltTQSFg4AuLuvvR4JDd5wqL-JYheuISVQ5hFPQWinf6ANgkYMA1DACNkHn2AeleYZFKUbORGT74IB4Jw2iwQPV2+GulGgPAQYAA5nEgA))

Now, you can actually call it and get a useful result. As written, you might sometimes get confusing type errors due to type inference, but that's typically resolved by adding additional type annotations. In particular I recommend adding a type annotation to the result of `compose`, e.g.

```
const plus5times3: number => number = pipe(plus5, times3);
```